# How to see a linked container as localhost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have these two containers:

```yaml
api:
  image: social-learning
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - ../api:/app
  expose:
    - "3000"
web:
  image: social-learning-frontend
  ports:
    - "4200:4200"
    - "9000:9000"
  command: ember serve -p 4200
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - api
  expose:
    - "3000"
```

When I do:

```
docker exec `docker ps -a | grep 'frontend_web_1' | awk '{print $1 }'` curl http://localhost:3000
```

I always get connection refused. I can access the other container through its IP but I'd prefer to do it as localhost.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here.

It looks like you are trying to log into the web container and access the api container using the localhost address? This isn't going to work.

The best solution is just to use the link you've declared; within the web container you should be able to do `curl http://api:3000`. This works because Docker has added an entry to `/etc/hosts` for the api container for you.

Accessing via `localhost` will only work from the Docker host, where the container ports are published. I guess you could access the Docker host from within the container via the Docker bridge (e.g. `curl 172.17.42.1:3000`), but that seems pointlessly complicated and brittle.

Comment: Cool, glad I was of some help.

Comment: Acutally I have to bind it on docker container localhost because the application does not support domain name. I have to give an IP and I would like to give 127.0.0.1 to avoid Docker dynamic IPs dealing.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It should be possible to map links to localhost... The code I'm running inside my container uses localhost for services (they used to run on the same machine and they still are with docker-compose).

Comment: @StevenRoose I guess you could use nc or similar to forward a local port in a container to a service running in another container. But the problem the OP had was not understanding that networking in containers is namespaced - my answer addresses that issue.

Comment: Container property --name is resolved as host in another containers in network. Also you can resolve container host in network using different ways : https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/